# maven-assembly-plugin fileset permissions changed?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, fileset

I have Maven 3.0.4 and am trying to make an assembly out of a couple of other artifacts. When using maven-assembly-plugin if I use a  it unpacks the artifact contents in the right place, but loses executable permissions on files (e.g. in a /bin directory). I've tried unpacking the dependency into target/ (I see permissions are still okay) and then using  to copy them into the assembly, but again, file permissions are lost. It would be really bad if I had to manually go through the dependency to figure out which files are executable.

Anybody have a way to work around these apparent bugs? Is it even possible to copy the files from their temp directory directly into the assembly final location and maintain permissions? If so, how?

Comment: You need to show your pom? what is your OS ? what is the error comes to you exactly ?

Comment: I guess I'm confused. When are your permissions lost? once you pack them to archive? or do you do some copy prior to that?

Comment: Here's an example. I create an artifact A with /bin/a.sh and permissions 0755. I create artifact B that wants to include A. Using a <dependencySet> tag in the maven-assembly-plugin for B will change a.sh to 0644. If instead I use maven-dependency-plugin to unpack artifact A under /target, it has the right permissions when unpacked. If I then use <fileSet> in the assembly to copy that unpacked set of files into B, again it changes a.sh to 0644. I want to keep permissions on everything from A included in B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The pom file that was the parent pom of the subproject where the assembly was being built had declared a workaround a couple years ago for maven-assembly-plugin bug MASSEMBLY-449. As part of that suggested workaround an  block was entered, with a default fileMode of 644. This was back when maven was on 2.2 and the m-a-p was also at 2.2. We switched to maven 3.0.4 and the m-a-p was updated to 2.4 a few months ago. By that point the bug was fixed. Apparently that fix meant that the workaround was no longer needed, and in fact interfered with execute-bit settings. When I removed the  block, all the execute permissions for both  and  entries were once again correct.

Answer (score 1):

The pom would really help here.  Are you are using `<directoryMode>` and/or `<fileMode>` in your dependency set, e,g.:

```
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>someDir</outputDirectory>
    <outputFileNameMapping></outputFileNameMapping>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
    <includes>
        <include>artifactA</include>
    </includes>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
</dependencySet>
```

`<fileSet>` has the same options.

Comment: When I get a few minutes today I'll upload the assembly-file code and pom example, but I just wanted to reply to this comment. I definitely do NOT want to use <directoryMode> or <fileMode>, because the artifact that's being download has a ton of files (e.g. an entire activemq installation) where the 0755 files are only a few, and not necessarily just in /bin. Basically, what I'm trying to find is a solution where maven just keeps the permissions the original artifact has, rather than screwing with them and forcing me to go find each file manually myself and fix it back the way it was.

Comment: Be aware you are somewhat at the mercy of the underlying operating system.  For example, on Unix, whatever the umask is set to will affect file creation.